# What layout is suitable for 800x1280 Android devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to differentiate the values ​​folder between a device with 720x1280 resolution and another with 800x1280 resolution (Samsung galaxy S3 and Galaxy Note).
The folder that I use for the galaxy s3 is values​​-sw360dp,

Which folder can I use to set the ​​galaxy note values?

My current values are:

[image]

Comment: The size in pixels is not very meaningful for the layout. What is the size of the other device measured in dip?

Comment: Galaxy Note : 800 x 1280 pixels, 5.3 inches (~285 ppi pixel density)
//
Galaxy s3: 720 x 1280 pixels, 4.8 inches (~306 ppi pixel density)

Comment: "I need to differentiate the values ​​folder between a device with 720x1280 resolution and another with 800x1280 resolution" -- why?

Comment: You don't get to *choose* which folder is used for a device. Android picks the folder that is best-fit for the device and takes the values within it. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking...